# No valid bower.json was found in any branch or tag of https://github.com/yiisoft/jquery-pjax.git

Tags: yii2, composer-php, bower

Hello I have some issue with composer installation after installing your package in composer globally. See the error below

```
[Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]
  No valid bower.json was found in any branch or tag of https://github.com/yiisoft/jquery-pjax.git, could not load a package from it
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to try these solution and usually its will be fixed:

1) if you have antivirus turn it off since its maybe block some of needed port.

2) run this command `composer clear-cache` in your project.

3) if first and second solution not work, then go to `/root/.composer` directory, and create file `config.json` and put these command inside it.

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "github-protocols": ["https","http"],
        "github-oauth": {
            "github.com": "YourGithubOauth"
        }
    }
}
```

then clear cache again. and I wish its work.

Good luck.

Comment: It works when I use clear-cache. Thanks, by the way whats the difference with composer clearcache and composer clear-cache?

Comment: Happy to hear that :), `composer clearcache` is an alias for `composer clear-cache`...you can check this: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#clear-cache-clearcache-

Comment: This link also may help https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/issues/123#issuecomment-361895567